# Average signal sum

Tags: matlab, cumulative-sum

I have a pretty naive question about calculating the cumulative sum of a signal, averaged over a certain period of time, as visible below:

[image]

So far, in the attempt of introducing a moving window effect, I've implemented the following:

```
persistent X

if isempty(X)
   X = x;
end

X = (1 - (Ts/T))*X + (Ts/T)*x;
```

with Ts being the discrete time-step and T the period through which I intend to average the cumulative sum.

Am I missing something or is the implementation right?

Comment: Your equation has a left-hand side that depends on _t_, but a right-hand size that doesn't (the limits of the summation index should probably be variable). Have you checked [`movmean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html)?

Comment: @LuisMendo: Using movmean is (unfortunately) no viable alternative.